# Can I modify a value in setting.setting file?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, properties

I am working on a Windows form application with C#,and it would be really helpful if I could modify a value in "setting.setting" file in the program properties. In fact I want to put connection string for SQL database in this file and get it when needed so I need to change it if the connection changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of Settings: Application-scope and User-scope. You can always change User-scope settings (like in @Alans answer), but changing Application-scope requires admin rights. The basic idea is that App-scope settings are only edited by an Admin (using Notepad or whatever).

Explanation: Settings are stored in `\Program Files\App\App.exe.config`, and you need to be admin to write in `\Program Files` (under Vista or restricted XP). User settings are stored in the Users Settings folder, the installed `.config` only contains the default value.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the value, then call: `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`

Comment: How to modify the value ,an error says that Properties.Settings.Default.connectionstring is read only